# getting error while requesting to salesforce from eclipse

Tags: ide, eclipse

[image: error mesage when doing any kind of request to salesforce from eclipse]

i have already try to close the eclipse and restart, it works but again after 4-5 request same error is coming.
any solution will be appreciate.

Error Message is This: Unable to create connection to Salesforce, Destination URl not reset. The URL returend rom login must be set in SForceService.

Comment: Please try to select appropriate tags related to the subject of your question. This will help attract people with the right knowledge. I've taken the liberty to do so for you, as there appeared no relation to saleforce1 or communities.

Comment: Are you trying to make some web service calls prior to `login` call? may be for debugging purposes?

Comment: Did you check trust.salesforce.com - I've seen these kind of errors when an instance is having problems.

Comment: Try setting up the credentials of your Force.com project again.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke actually, this problem is related to salesforce,ide and eclipse. i pardon, that i forget to include ide and eclipse tag. so i am adding salesforce again.

Comment: @highfive no, i am not doing so. I am doing any kind of request like, refresh from server, save to server, save the code, debug..etc..actually, it is not allowing to connect with salesforce,,issue is like this..

Comment: @PepeFloyd i have tried things like, credentials reset, again setup new project, close eclipse. but all is vain.

Comment: Ankuli, this entire site is dedicated to salesforce and related technologies. No need for using a general salesforce tag.